# Cannot read property 'add'. Rxjs Subscription

Tags: angular, angular7, subscription, rxjs6, unsubscribe

I started to optimize my code and i want to unsubscribe from my subscriptions in ngOndestroy. I have multiple subscription.
The problem is when i want to invoke the add() method to add additional child subscriptions it says Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.
I simplified my code here so you can see the important things only.

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
     private subscription: Subscription;
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.getData();
   this.getFeed();
}

ngOndestroy {
if (this.subscription) {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   console.log(this.subscription);
   }
}

getData() {
   const subscription = this._authService.currentCompanyId.subscribe((newCompanyId) => {
            this.driverSubs(newCompanyId);
            this.vehicleSubs(newCompanyId);
        });
        this.subscription.add(subscription);
    }

   driverSubs(newCompanyId) {
        const subscription = this._driversService.getAllDrivers(newCompanyId).subscribe((data) => {
            this.getDataForDrivers(data);
        });
        this.subscription.add(subscription);
    }

    vehicleSubs(newCompanyId) {
        const subscription = this._vehiclesService.getAllVehicles(newCompanyId).subscribe((data) => {
            this.getDataForVehicles(data);
        });
        this.subscription.add(subscription);
    }
}

getFeed() {
    this.feedSubs();
    this.feedTachoSubs();
}

feedSubs() {
    const subscription = this._feedService.getFeed().subscribe(response => {
        this.feed = response;
    });
    this.subscription.add(subscription);
}

feedTachoSubs() {
    const subscription = this._feedTachoService.getFeedForVehicles().subscribe(response => {
        this.feedTacho = response;
    });
    this.subscription.add(subscription);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel said, your class member must be an array of subscriptions to handle all of them.

In addition to his responses, I would suggest to use the "async pipe" wherever you can, so the angular will do the unsubscribe by itself.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution - Although the answer of **Daniel** do the trick, he is holding an array of different Subscription objects.
If you'd like to hold only *ONE* Subscription, and whenever you unsubscribe you want all of them to unsubscribe as well.
You simply create this.

```
private subscriptions: Subscription;
```

and then, in the constructor you init the object:

```
this.subscriptions = new Subscription();
```

and then you can use:

```
this.subscriptions.add( ... Your subscription... );
```

when you want to unsubscribe:

```
if(this.subscriptions){
  this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

and all of child subscription would unsubscribe as well.
---
When you tried to .add() subscription your main Subscription was undefined, thats why you couldn't add new one.

Comment: Yes. The first answer was very good. This seems more appropriate and easier for me tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your field should not be `private subscription: Subscription;` but:

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
```

-> i.e. an array. And then you will add the subscriptions to it with:

```
this.subscriptions.push(subscription)
```

In `ngOnDestroy`, you will then have to iterate that array and unsubscribe each subscription:

```
for(const subscription of this.subscriptions) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Well. It's a nice solution. Thank you. You saved a programmer's life today.
https://imgur.com/1OvMCpW